# Why relative import is not useful in python?

Tags: python-3.x, stable-diffusion

I am downloading the stable-diffusion 2.0
when I use

> python script/txt2img.py

got an unexpected error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldm'

i have the same problem in sd-v1.5,but to change the code in txt2img i got successfully
from

> from ldm.util import instantiate_from_config

to

> from ..ldm.util import instantiate_from_config

but now i only got  an error:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I am confused about that.

Know someone who can answer? I am grateful to your answer